# odd behavior of strftime in ZF2

Tags: php, localization, zend-framework2, strftime

I'm trying to show a localized date with strftime but it does not work.

```
class ExampleController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $openDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(...);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, Locale::getDefault());
        Debug::dump(Locale::getDefault()); // shows 'fr_FR'
        Debug::dump(strftime('%B %Y', $openDate->getTimestamp())); // shows 'August 2013' instead of 'Août 2013'

    }
}
```

In module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
return array(

    ...

    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'fr_FR',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),

    ...

);
```

Is someone can tell me why the month is not translated in French ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` has nothing to do with ZF2 or the `intl` php extension. However ZF2 does come with a `DateFormat` view helper that should solve your problem. The full documentation is available at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.i18n.view.helpers.html#dateformat-helper

A quick example:

```
Debug::dump($this->dateFormat($openDate->getTimestamp(), IntlDateFormatter::LONG));
```

The default locale for the `DateFormat` view helper is that returned by `Locale::getDefault()` therefore it should return the date in french as you require.

To use your custom format:

```
Debug::dump($this->dateFormat($openDate->getTimestamp(), IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::LONG, null, "dd LLLL Y - HH:mm"));
```

Comment: I had seen the dateFormat view helper already. But it only accepts IntlDateFormatter constants. I need a specific date format as strftime('%d %B %Y - %H:%M').

Comment: @Martial if you need finer control over the format you can use the underlying `IntlDateFormatter` directly. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php specifically the `pattern` parameter (Note the `dateFormat` view helper simply invokes this)

Comment: @Martial I have updated my answer showing how you do this using the view helper.

Answer (score 0):

According what Tomdarkness said, I found a way to do what I wanted. I used IntlDateFormatter :

```
$formatter = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
    \Locale::getDefault(), // fr_FR
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    \IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Paris',
    \IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd LLLL Y - HH:mm'
);

echo $formatter->format($openDate); // shows '20 août 2013 - 14:39'
```

I think maybe I will code my own dateFormat view helper based on this.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see you answered your own question before replying to your comments. You do not need to do this. I edited my answer showing you how can get your custom format with the view helper rather then creating new objects in the view which is bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Why the doc does not mention the fifth parameter?

Comment: The documentation for ZF2 is not exactly excellent, it is one of the weak points of the framework in my opinion. I normally find it useful to not just rely on the documentation but also look at the API docs and even the actual source.